# How to access next to next element in linked list in C?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am learning C and got confusion. For example:

```
typedef struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
}entry;

entry n1, n2, n3;
int i;

n1.value = 100;
n2.value = 200;
n3.value = 300;

n1.next = &n2;
n2.next = &n3;
```

the value of `n2` node can be accessible by `(*n1.next).value` or by `n1.next->value`. It works. But let's say I want to directly access the `n3` value by:

```
(n1.next).next -> value

(*(n1.next).next).value
```

The Compiler comlains

```
error: request for member `next' in something not a structure or union
```

Why so?

Comment: Nice moustache by the way.

Comment: I am getting error becuase I have nice moustache? :)

Comment: "Is it possible" -- just think for a minute: Do you really believe that the answer is no, this is completely impossible?

Comment: yes, possible may be bit harsh to say. I changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're missing a `*`. It should be:

```
(*(*n1.next).next).value
    ^^                   first node
  ^^^^^^^^^^             second node
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       third node
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ third node's value
```

Or `n1.next->next->value` for short.

Comment: Why is it needed to have dereferencing at `n1.next`. As I understand first If I have `n1.next` I point to the address of next node then if I write `(n1.next).next` now I am pointing to next next node `n3`. Now I can use dereference Operator to Access the value.

Comment: @GulluButt No... you use a dereference operator to access the thing a pointer points to. `n1.next` is a pointer that points to n2, so `*n1.next` is n2.

Comment: damn, you write faster :D

Comment: I got it now. pointer is just if you point your finger to some city let's say and `*pointer` is if you go into the City ?